# translate: Today I worked through 2 chapters of my grammar book

Tags: translation

How do I translate this?

> Today I completed 2 chapters of my grammar book

The grammar book being an instructional book on Chinese grammar with exercises.

My best guess

> 今天我做两章完了语法的书

Comment: Not a native speaker, my attempt: 今天我完成阅读了两篇语法书章。

Comment: 今天我做了两章语法书的练习... btw, '做两章完了' is ungrammatical, it should be '做完了两章'.

Comment: The word "complete" is quite unclear. It seems currently, some native speakers here interpret it as "finish the exercises of two chapters". But, do you mean "finish reading two chapters, and get their exercises done"?

Comment: Stan yes... finish reading the two chapters, including doing the exercises... Thanks user58955. I think with that change I'd be pretty close?

Comment: 我今天学完了两章语法书。（做完了两章练习题。）

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this

我今天做完了两章语法练习题

Comment: hi user3306356, except I'm not talking about the exercises specifically, I mean reading the entire chapters, and also doing the exercises at the end.

Comment: @SamuelParsonage 我今天语法书学了两章